# Why is my Wordpress Ajax function not working on mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website hosted on 20i. I'm almost certain that everything worked fine until I pointed the a records to get the website off its test domain and onto the actual one, this might be unrelated but I figured I'd mention it incase. Anyway for some reason my Ajax function works fine on desktop but not on mobile. When I look at it on mobile none of the posts are visible and if I select a filter nothing happens. Does anyone know what this could be? I've looked around for answers but I can't seem to find the solution.

Here's my code;

**jQuery**

```
// submit form function
jQuery('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $ = jQuery; 
    var filter = $('#form');
    var form_data = $('#form').serializeArray();
    $('#load_more').data('page', 1);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function(response){
            $('#loop').empty();

            for( var i = 0; i < response.post_cont.length; i++ ){
                var html =''+
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-4 column">'+
                        '<a href="'+ response.post_cont[i].permalink +'">'+
                            '<div class="card" style="width: 100%;">'+
                                '<div class="post_image" style="background-image: url('+ response.post_cont[i].image +');"></div>'+

                                '<div class="card-body">'+
                                    '<h5 class="card-title">'+ response.post_cont[i].title +'</h5>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</div>';

                $('#loop').append(html);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**php AJAX function**

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter');
    add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter');

    // this function runs after it is called inside our_work_ajax.js
    function filter(){

        if( $_POST['type'] && !empty($_POST['type']) ){
            $category = $_POST['type'];
        }else{ 
            $category = array( 'Assisted Needs/Residential', 'Commercial/Educational', 'Private Housing', 'Social-Housing' );
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'our_work',
            'posts_per_page'    => 9,
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'tax_query'         => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'category',
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'terms'         => $category
                )
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        $no_of_posts = $query->found_posts;

        if( $query->have_posts() ):
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 

                $main_field = get_field('Images');
                $first_row = $main_field[0];
                $img = $first_row['Image'];
                $imgsize = $img['sizes']['large'];

                // creating an array of content needed from array
                $post_cont[] = array(
                    "permalink" => get_the_permalink(),
                    "image" =>  $imgsize,
                    "title" =>  get_the_title(),
                );
            endwhile; 
        endif;

        // array getting the total number of posts 
        $max_posts[] = array(
            "no_of_posts"   => $no_of_posts
        );
        // converting arrays into json and submitting it to the ajax_url for the .js file
        echo json_encode(array( "post_cont" => $post_cont, "max_posts" => $max_posts));
        wp_reset_postdata();
        die();
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">

    <div id="filters">
        <div class="option">
            <p>Assisted Needs/Residential</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Assisted Needs/Residential">
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <p>Commercial/Educational</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Commercial/Educational">
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <p>Private Housing</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Private Housing">
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <p>Social Housing</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Social Housing">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filter">
</form>

<div id="loop" class="row">

</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var inputs = $('#form .option input');

    inputs.each(function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $('#form').submit();
});
</script>
```

**AJAX url inside functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'all_js', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );
```

Comment: You should add `console.log` in your JS to see what is being executed and what's not. (test form submit, ajax success and fail etc...)

Comment: @Mtxz everything is fine on desktop, its just mobile thats the issue and I can't view the console.log on mobile. Thanks

Comment: Well, my guess is that your scripts are running slower on mobile, on so maybe the onSubmit handler is not properly set. There are ways to get a proper debugger on iOs or Android (search for iOs webkit debugger or android chrome remote debug). If you cannot test with console.log, just use `alert()` to see which part of your code is running and which is.

Comment: If you use an Android device then you can see the console in Chrome, for iOS you can use Safari. Just connect the phone, and set some developer settings in the browser.